# partial word search in solr example: sarvesh , i want search like rves

Tags: solr

examples:Beautiful
search based: auti...
I would like to search with only part of a word, not the whole word.
For example when I search `auti` only the middle 3 letters ,not the whole word.I am not getting results : For the moment I am using the search api with apache solr (and perhaps views).
Any suggestions please?
I am using this one

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use wildcard query.

In your example above, you should prepend and append your search terms with an asterix, so if someone searches for auti, the query you send to server will be *auti*

This should pull all results with all words that contain the word auti within them.

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. but iam searching for example:world searching http://localhost:8984/solr/select?q=name:worl. it displaying result.search last word ie *rld,that time also dispalying, but search without entring * astrik like orld, not displaying result.

Comment: Ohh... it is because you are using EdgeNGramFilterFactory in your fieldtype above, and the string value World gets broken down to the following terms: "w", "wo", "wor", "worl", "world" , that's why you can search for "worl" but not "orld" Please take a look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Comment: The wildcard query does not account for index-time boosts.

Answer (score 1):

Now since you wanna search for sub-strings inside words, you can add side="back" to your definition, and that should help you achieve your goal.

So your fieldtype definition will look like this:

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10" side="front" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10" side="back" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```