# Query with Solr and MySQL in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml, solr

I have a MySQL DB indexed with Solr, and for my purpose I need to query the data inside this DB.
I'd like to perform "soft" query, like every search engine on the web.

I'm trying to set two sample field inside schema.xml

```
<uniqueKey>organization_id</uniqueKey>

<field name="organization_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

This is my solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
 class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

And, finally, data-config.xml

`<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/organizations2" user="****" password="****" />
    <document name="content">
        <entity name="id" query="SELECT * FROM organization"
            deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM organization" 
            deltaQuery="SELECT * FROM organization">
            <field column="organization_id" name="organization_id" />
            <field column="name" name="name" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>`

It's possible to make classic query, with a similar organization name, and then return the correct company?
I'm trying to search all day but no solution.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First ensure the solr instance is [running](https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Running+Solr) by checking the solr Admin at 8983 port.

Next is to see if you are able to search from solr Admin [query](https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Query+Screen) screen.

The name field in schema.xml can be "text_string" instead of "string" to support [LIKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902512/solr-query-with-like-clause) queries.

Since i am not sure if you are looking for a way to search from Java program based on the question, following lists the options to search from Java:
You can search from Java using Apache's [solrj](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html) package or through `URLOpener+InputStreamReader+xpath` combination.

Sample java snippet using solrj to search for data:

```
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("company name");
```

Sample java snippet using URLOpener+InputStreamReader+xpath to search for data:

```
String solrQuery = "http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=company name";
URLOpener uop = new URLOpener();
URLConnection conn= uop.openURL(solrQuery);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
//Read the contents into string variable qryContent
Document xmlDocument = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(
new ByteArrayInputStream(qryContent.getBytes()));
XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
String titleExpression = "/response/result/doc/arr[@name='name']/str";
NodeList allTitleNodes = 
(NodeList)xPathExpression.evaluate(titleExpression,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to search from a Java program, in particular I'm developing a web-app with Play Framework, and I need to search inside my DB indexed with Solr.

Comment: Not work, it's necessary to specify the COMPLETE and CORRECT name of a company. I need to have company based on similarity name, not the exact one.

Comment: @Fabio 
Try adding [solr.NGramFilterFactory](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/apache-solr-configuring-partial-word-search-functionality/2012-12-12) or [solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472565/partial-word-search-in-solr-example-sarvesh-i-want-search-like-rves) in your shcmea.xml to perform search for partial words. Example: `<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" mingramsize="3" maxgramsize="25"/>` for fieldtype `solr.TextField`

Comment: I can't understand how does it work, what about fuzzy search in Solr?